# How to make div width almost 100%

Tags: html, css

I have such a html code:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make #inner div to have width 100% of #outer but minus 10px?

Here is my css:

```
#outer {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Please note that my answer is not technically correct; the padding on the `#outer` will instead grow the `#outer` element `10px` total, and the `#inner` will be `500px` in my first example. This is because `padding` is additive to element width. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtaCM/2/ On further reflection, @thirtydot's answer is correct, but only if the inner element's width is set to `auto` (and it's not set to a finite value or to `inherit`). My answer might still work for you, but I wanted to point out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**

See ThirtyDot's answer, as it does not impact the outer element's width:

[How to make div width almost 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620256/how-to-make-div-width-almost-100/7620275#7620275)

The below will actually make the outer element's width total the width plus the padding left and right values, which is not what the question is asking. Sorry for the confusion. `:)`

---

You could add a padding left and right of `5px` (assuming you want the `#inner` to be `10px` less total, not per side):

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>

#outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZtaCM/

**EDIT**

Taking into account the `max-width` property, see this demo:

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeWidth('400px')" value="Change to 400px"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeWidth('500px')" value="Change to 500px"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeWidth('600px')" value="Change to 600px"/>
</p>

#outer {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: red;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
#test {
  background: yellow;
  width: 600px;
}

function changeWidth(width) {
    document.getElementById('test').style.width = width;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZtaCM/1/

Comment: In this case the full width of #outer div is equal to 510px.

Comment: The reason I ended up switching to `padding` (and forgetting that padding is additive in the meantime) is because if the `#inner` has a `100%` width, the margin only shows on the left. So I'm wondering how to get around that if the `#inner` has a set width (maybe, `99%` or some other number).

Answer (score 4):

Simply set a `margin-left` and/or a `margin-right` of `10px`:

```
#inner {
    margin: 0 10px
}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/xrmAE/1/

Change `10px` to `5px` if required.

Comment: I'm wondering about something. The above works, but only if the `#inner` inherits the width of the `#outer`. When I had worked on my fiddle initially, I set the `#inner` width to `100%`, noticed that the margin only showed on the left, and switched it to padding on the `#outer`, which is actually wrong, since it adds `10px` to the `#inner` width, not subtracts it. Is it only possible to do this then when the inner element inherits the width of the outer?

Comment: @JaredFarrish #inner div does not inherit the width from #outer div. Inner div uses a default value of `width: auto`.

Comment: @Karolis - Bah. I'm having a rough morning.

Comment: It's not that it's inheriting the width (confusing terminology because inherit means something else), it's that the `width` of `#inner` is set to `auto`. But yes, it's only possible to do this when the inner element has `width` set to `auto`. If you [check the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth) (let's forget about `padding`/`border`): `'margin-left' + 'width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I got sidetracked in the middle of writing the above comment, so I didn't see the issue had already been explained. Oh well.

Comment: That's fine, I appreciate the explanation. I think it's an important distinction, and not just because it caught me when I wasn't paying attention. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

What about `padding: 10px` for `#outer`?